# TSQL: Update language related descriptions for time table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, time

I have a problem which is bother me for a long with dynamic setting and updating of descriptions for a time table and the language related settings.

I have a table called dbo.time_language which is containing the order (1,2,3) of the language, the LCID of the country (1031, 1033, 1036) and the alias (German, English, France).

Now I want to update my table dbo.time with a day_desc_1, day_desc_2 and day_desc_3 and so on for month, quarter, etc.

```
  [Day]                          = CONVERT (CHAR(8),[Date],112)
  ,[Day_Desc_1]                   = NULL 
  ,[Day_Desc_2]                   = NULL
  ,[Day_Marker]                   = NULL

  ,[Month]                        = DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])
  ,[Month_Desc_1]                 = NULL
  ,[Month_Desc_2]                 = NULL
  ,[Month_Marker]                 = NULL

  ,[Quarter]                      = DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date])
  ,[Quarter_Desc_1]               = NULL
  ,[Quarter_Desc_2]               = NULL
  ,[Quarter_Marker]               = NULL
```

The point is, I want to update these descriptions leading to the order of the dbo.time_language (1,2,3) which should be orderable like everyone need it.

Comment: AFAIK, you can simply use the built-in `SET LANGUAGE` of sql server that will do the translations for you, I'm quite sure these 3 languages comes built in.

Comment: thank you for the fast response. Somehow I have it in my mind, that changing the language in a session is not the best practise?

Comment: Maybe it's better to move this problem at application level and keep in SQL only a date. What if you need additional languages in future?

Comment: thats exactly my point, i want to control the descriptions / the order in my table dbo.time_language where i can add an additional language. I have written a WHILE argument to set dynamic the @language and dateformat, but i would need to use the setted dateformat for converting my char 'yyyymmdd' to the format of the country

Answer (score 0):

For the moment i am trying this:

```
DECLARE @i          INT = (SELECT MIN([htl_Desc]) FROM [dbo].[tbl_help_time_language])
DECLARE @j          INT = (SELECT MAX([htl_Desc]) FROM [dbo].[tbl_help_time_language])
DECLARE @language   NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @dateformat NVARCHAR(10)

WHILE @i < @j
BEGIN
  --PRINT @i
  SET @language     = (SELECT [htl_alias]  FROM  [dbo].[tbl_help_time_language] WHERE [htl_Desc]=@i)
  SET @dateformat   = (SELECT [dateformat] FROM  [dbo].[tbl_help_time_language] WHERE [htl_Desc]=@i)
  SET LANGUAGE @language
  SET DATEFORMAT @dateformat

  UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_help_time] SET [Day_Desc_1] = 'get the right format and convert to leading country'

  --PRINT @dateformat
  --PRINT @i
  SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Maybe I can to a small matching table or so, but at the moment I have no idea how to do that dynamically.